# How to generate a new Page on a certain event (next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I know the title is confusing, but basically, I want to generate a page on a certain event is triggered (i.e. a button is clicked).

For example, when you make an account on a service like twitter, how exactly does it generate a unique page for your profile (like https://www.twitter.com/exampleuser1234)? This has always confused me and I'd love an answer.

I have searched and scanned Google far and wide, and I could not find any clues at all.
I don't even know how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using dynamic routes, e.g. `/users/[id]`.

You can learn more in the documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes